# How to use a switch to turn a timer on without the timer turning itself off?

Tags: terraria

I have a bunch of heart statues each hooked up to their own 1-second-timer for fighting The Moon Lord. Right now, I have to turn each individual timer on. This isn't a huge deal, but it would be nice if I could have a simple single button that will put every timer in the "on" state with one click. Is this possible with the current wiring system in Terraria?

Comment: why can't you just wire it up to the same switch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just hook all the statues up to the same timer. They will all activate at the same time. Putting them on different timer's doesn't provide any further benefits.

Comment: Oh. Duh. I guess I had thought the 10 second thing was timer dependent, not statue dependent. Now I feel silly.

Comment: What 10 second thing? There can only be 3 heart pickups within a certain area.

Comment: Heart statues can only be triggered every 10 seconds.

Comment: yes that's true but doesn't affect anything if you're using 1-second timers, it just won't activate 9/10 + when there are too many hearts in the area already

Comment: Oh I understand what you thought, yeh that's a misconception, it's statue dependent. So just put them all on the same triggering wire

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 statues(having more wouldn't even work) you could use different wire colors. Then use a single color for a statue. Just make sure the wires don't overlap the timer or statue.